# How to bold only secont element in css

Tags: html, css

How can i bold only second  element in css
I want to change only >Products< but cannot change the html code.

`

```
<header>
        <nav>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">Products</a>
            <a href="#">About Us</a>
            <a href="#">Contacts</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

`

Bold only  Products

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```css
header nav a:nth-child(2) {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a style block with the `font-weight: bold` property targeting the second `<a>` element like so:

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Products</a>
    <a href="#">About Us</a>
    <a href="#">Contacts</a>
  </nav>
</header>

<style>
header nav a:nth-of-type(2) {
  font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
```